# Navigation bar behaviour in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have three view controllers and they are embedded in navigation controller.

The architecture is the following:
[image]

I want to hide navigation bar from first view controller.

For this purpose I use

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

in viewdidload method(for first controller).
The same is used in two other controllers but with false parameter to enable navigation bar.

When I load application - all is good, NB is disabled, when I go to second controller also all is fine - it is enabled. BUT! When I press back button on navigation bar of second controller and it sends user to first controller - navigation bar is enabled there.

Is there a special method which should be used when we return back to controller? Can anybody explain this to me? Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press back button, your view controller `viewDidLoad` method is not called again (because controller is not recreated) and navigation bar will have the same state as it had before you went back.

In order to update navigation bar for each view controller as it is shown, you have to update it in `viewWillAppear` method instead of `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

Use it in viewController's viewWillAppear method.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }
```